# running python script by php give null result on macOS

Tags: python, php

so I'm trying to execute a python file version 3.9 file using php via VScode and safari browser I spent hours trying to figure out what is the problem because it keep giving me null result

here is my code on php file

```
<?php 


$result =  shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3  fr/fr_load.py");
var_dump($result);

?>
```

I tried other python file with only print command and they worked just fine so my connection is fine but I can't figure out what is the problem

my python code is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3



#import the required libraries
import cv2

import joblib

from sys import exit


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd




# function to detect face from image
def face_detection(image_to_detect):
    #converting the image to grayscale since its required for eigen and fisher faces
    image_to_detect_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_to_detect, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # load the pretrained model for face detection
    # haarcascade is recommended for Eigenface  
    face_detection_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('php/fr/models/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

    
    # detect all face locations in the image using classifier
    all_face_locations = face_detection_classifier.detectMultiScale(image_to_detect_gray)
    
    # if no faces are detected
    if (len(all_face_locations) == 0):
        return None, None
    
    #splitting the tuple to get four face positions
    x,y,width,height = all_face_locations[0]
    #[0] cuz we assume we have only one face on our data set
    
    #calculating face coordinates
    face_coordinates = image_to_detect_gray[y:y+width, x:x+height]
    
   
    #for traning and testting all images should be at same size (for egien)
    face_coordinates = cv2.resize(face_coordinates,(500,500)) #we can use any number fit for us
    
    #return the face detected and face location
    return face_coordinates, all_face_locations[0] #all_face_locations[0] beacuse there is only one face in each image

names =[]
names.append("steve jobs")   
names.append("ali alramadan") 
names.append("hillary clinton")


#########load recognition model for later use ###########
face_classifier = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()

face_classifier.read("php/fr/models/our model.yml")

        
######## prediction ##############
#path of the image we want to test and predict 
image_to_classify = cv2.imread("php/fr/dataset/testing/load.jpg")




#make a copy of the image cuz we dont want to ruin the actual image by writing on it
image_to_classify_copy = image_to_classify.copy()

#get the face from the image
face_coordinates_classify, box_locations = face_detection(image_to_classify_copy)  

#if no faces are returned
if face_coordinates_classify is None:
    print("There are no faces in the image to classify")
    exit()
    
#if face is returned then predict the face
name_index, distance = face_classifier.predict(face_coordinates_classify) #if distance is big then there is big different between the train image and test image

name = names[name_index]
distance = abs(distance)

print(name)


#draw bounding box and text for the face detected
(x,y,w,h) = box_locations
cv2.rectangle(image_to_classify,(x,y),(x+w, y+h),(0,255,0),2)
cv2.putText(image_to_classify,name,(x,y-5),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,2.5,(0,255,0),2)



#show the image in window
cv2.imshow("Prediction "+name, cv2.resize(image_to_classify, (500,500)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

any suggestions please?

Comment: `This function can return null both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required.` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec

Comment: the python file is working perfectly fine there is no error

Comment: maybe use `logging` (or normal file) to write information which line of code was executed. You could also use `try/except` to catch errors and write in file or `logging`. Code may have many problems. ie. it may run in different folder and it may not find your image and `yml`. Especially that you run with path `fr/fr_load.py` but your image has path `php/fr/...` - so it may search it in wrong place. Maybe in Python first check `Current Working DIrectory` - `print( os.getcwd() )`

Comment: thanks for answering but the direction is fine because if I write print command in the first line of python file it works fine and return the result but once I write print under  import libraries lines it return null and as I said I run the python code alone it was working fine with no errors